# Evaluation of @CanExecute for RCP e4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

A RCP E4 application includes a TreeViewer to manage the visivility/selection of a collection of “Packages”. The part is named as Package Navigator.

[image]

When one Package is ready to be send, the TreeViewer icon shows
[image]
and the button to start the shipment [image]
should be enabled.

When the package is not ready, the icon is [image]
and the button (handler) to ship should be disabled.

The code to implement such
behavior is:

```java
private TreeViewer viewer;
    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent, IEnviosService theModel) {
        ...         
        Tree t = (Tree) viewer.getControl();
        t.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                boolean check = false;
                System.out.print("Selection listener ....");
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
                if (selection.getFirstElement() instanceof Package) {
                    check = ((Package)selection.getFirstElement()).isReadyToShip();
                    System.out.print("IT'S A PACKAGE....");
                    // evaluate all @CanExecute methods
                    broker.post(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, check);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        });
    }
```

The handler to execute the shipment is

```java
public class ShipmentHandler {
    @Execute
    public void execute(Shell shell) {
        //TODO
    }
    
    @Inject
    @Optional
    @CanExecute
    public boolean canExecute(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC) boolean checkPackageReady) {
        System.out.println("Inside canExecute method... " + checkPackageReady);
        if (checkPackageReady)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the button never is disabled, even whe the @canExecute method returns false, for example, after click on Packages 88 , 89 and 110 and 112 shows the following console output whith the button always enabled:

```
Selection listener  PACKAGE: 88...true
Inside canExecute method... true
Selection listener  PACKAGE: 89...false
Inside canExecute method... false
Selection listener  PACKAGE: 110...false
Inside canExecute method... false
Selection listener  PACKAGE: 112...true
Inside canExecute method... true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can mix `@CanExecute` and `@UIEventTopic` like that. In any case `UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC` is a rather special topic which isn't intended to be handled like this.

The argument to the `broker.post(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC` is supposed to be an element id, `UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID` or a `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.Selector`, nothing else. The argument selects which handlers are updated.

So you can't pass the 'checkPackageReady' value directly to the handler, you will have to use some other mechanism - such as a model object that the view and the handler can both inject.

You could also use the `ESelectionService` to set the current selection for the part, you can then access this information in the handler:

View part:

```java
@Inject 
ESelectionService selectionService;

...

public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
{
  selectionService.setSelection(viewer.getStructuredSelection());

  broker.post(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, ... selector);
}
```

Can execute:

```java
@CanExecute
public boolean canExecute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SELECTION) IStructuredSelection selection, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART)  MPart part)
{
  // TODO check part is your part
  // TODO check the selection
}
```